# Studies of the impact on research of measuring research output via publication statistics?

Tags: publications, research-process

Are there any studies of the impact on research choices (i.e. which research topics do researcher choose, how likely they are to collaborate with others, whether they go to public or private research institutions, etc.) of measuring research output via publication statistics, such as publication numbers, citation numbers, or combination of both (H-index)?

**BACKGROUND**

Given a finite amount of resources and an infinite amount of questions about the functioning of the universe, some priorities must be established regarding the distribution of resources. In alignment with (Lord) Kelvin's quote of "If you can not measure it, you can not improve it", and with the neo liberal perspective which have been seeping into most branches of society, most institutions dealing with researchers (whether to hire them or to fund them) aim to measure their output, mostly so that they can incent and/or pressure them into "improving" such output, most often by selecting the researchers or research project with "the best output". Among the many options available to measure such "output", the main ones (and their variations) are the number of publications (passing various criteria of quality, depending of the variation); the number of citations (passing various criteria of quality, depending of the variation); and combinations of both (e.g. H-index, number of publications which have been cited a given number of times, within a restricted set of publications).

**PROBLEM**

Beyond the *Observer's effect*, the fact that any act of observation affects the observed system, the objective of selecting individuals and projects based on the results of such observation is to push the system in some direction, and the measures used to observe and select researchers and/or research projects do affect which and how researchers are recruited and research projects are executed.

**BROAD QUESTION**

How much alignment is there between a) the direction(s) in which institutions mean to incent researchers and research projects and b) the consequences of the choices made by researchers in reaction to such incentives?

**MORE PRECISE QUESTION**

Among the few measurable choices made by researchers (e.g. the simple choice of collaborating with fellow researchers can be measured by the average number of co-authors in publications in a given time period and scientific community, such as identified by a journal or conference), are there some which are noticeably distinct between communities (identified by nationality, scientific area, gender, or other criteria) with distinct research output measures and/or incentive policies?

**SIDE NOTE**

This is a sequel to another [question I asked more than 8 years ago](https://%20https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43448/what-behaviors-desirable-or-not-are-encouraged-by-an-incentive-system-based-on), about which behaviors are encouraged by such incentive system. Now that I am "Associate Professor", I would like to dedicate more time to such questions (and hopefully not wait 10 more years until I am (hopefully) "Full Professor"!), even though they do not directly fall into my research area.

Comment: There is of course a large field of people who research research and researchers. Many of the questions you ask are extensively debated in the literature. What have you already done to find starting points to this literature? This is not a good site to ask for where to find a whole research community.

Comment: See [Loss of sustainability in scientific work](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/ac6ca1) for a related study.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth What is the name of the "large field" concern with researching research and researchers? I apologize if it is obvious to you (and not the right place to ask about it), but I have been in academia for 21 years (since the defense of my PhD in 2002) and am not aware of such publications nor researchers, hence my question. The articles that I found are specific to research areas (like physics for the useful article pointed out by ZeroTheHero, thanks!)

Comment: I believe that this is a part of econometrics.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth It does not seem to match? <<Econometrics is an application of statistical methods to economic data in order to give empirical content to economic relationships. More precisely, it is "the quantitative analysis of actual economic phenomena based on the concurrent development of theory and observation, related by appropriate methods of inference".>> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Econometrics

Comment: Aren't incentives and how researchers perform their work economic questions?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth You have a point, but I fear that Co author colusions (add me to your paper and I will add you) and citation colusions (cite me and I will cite you) would be so specific to academic researchers that economic researchers would refuse to consider it? I will inquire.